# Does magically resizing a construct change its HP?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, creature-size, hit-points, constructs

In Pathfinder Constructs gain bonus HP based on their size category.

Our group is working with the 3rd Party System "Spheres of Power" and one of the players plans to use the Minimize/Maximize and [Potent Alteration talents](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#TOC-Creation-Talents) from the playtest of the creation magic book to change the size of constructs in combat, and the question came up — does changing the size of a construct after it's made affect its HP?

Comment: Is the player resizing the construct at creation time, or in combat? What ability is he using to resize it?

Comment: @GreySage He's using the talent "Minimize/Maximize" from the playtest of the creation magic book, in conjunction with the Potent Alteration talent.

He would be using this in combat.

Comment: I didn't find anything called Minimize/Maximize in the Spheres of Power rules. Maybe quoting the ability in its exact words would be helpful because for now, I cannot conclude anything.

Comment: I cannot find anything about this either. Please quote the entire text of the ability.

Comment: Cody, did you mean [Size Change](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#TOC-Size-Change)?

Answer (score 5):

The following is taken from [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/) concerning temporary/permanent increases to ability scores.

> **Temporary Bonuses:** Temporary increases to your Constitution score give
>   you a bonus on your Fortitude saving throws. In addition, multiply
>   your total Hit Dice by this bonus and add that amount to your current
>   and total hit points. When the bonus ends, remove this total from your
>   current and total hit points.
>
> **Permanent Bonuses:** Ability bonuses with a duration greater than 1 day
>   actually increase the relevant ability score after 24 hours. Modify
>   all skills and statistics as appropriate. This might cause you to gain
>   skill points, hit points, and other bonuses. These bonuses should be
>   noted separately in case they are removed.

[Bears Endurance](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/bearSEndurance.html) goes into detail explaining that hit points gained from temporary bonuses to Constitution are NOT considered Temp HP. With this in-mind, I think it fair that the animated object would in-fact gain the hit point increase, using Bears Endurance as a template for how they are treated.

Comment: Thank you for adding citation about this. (I've removed the citation notice.) That citation about temporary bonuses makes it seem like it's a temporary bonus to their real HP, rather than a temporary bonus to their temporary HP, unless I'm misunderstanding how Pathfinder's rules are expressed and these are the same thing.

Comment: Just checked, because the text was ambiguous as to whether the hit points granted by a temp CON increase were considered temporary hit points or not, and found the answer in Bears Endurance, which explicitly state that the hit points gain from temp increases to Constitution are  NOT considered temporary hit points.

Comment: I think having your old ideas there and then having “EDIT” for the actual answer you’re going with is needlessly confusing. Signaling edits like that is generally frowned upon here anyway; we have a robust history system that can allow anyone to look through various versions of any answer anyway, so it isn’t really necessary. I would strongly recommend just editing your answer complete to just offer the answer you want to recommend, without concern for ideas you gave before but ended up deciding don’t apply.